# BASH Searching array for multiple strings in a loop

Tags: arrays, bash, parsing, cisco

Hello all and thanks for reading,

I am trying to write a script that will parse through Cisco Configs and determine which interfaces are or not in a specific vlan and if they are shutdown or not.  I thought it would be easy enough to parse through the array and search for the items that I was looking for and set a varialble for them I have run into some problems.  Below is the basic part of the script, this reads the file into the array and the echo just dumps the array.  What I am looking for is a way to read the array for three things:

- interface name
- switchport access vlan
- shutdown

The basic flow is that the script (interfaces.sh) reads in any *.cfg file and reads the interfaces in as an array.  At this point it parses through the arrays searching for those fields.  If found, set a value to be used later.  At the end, it takes the values for VLAN and isShut and based on their values, it reports if the interface is in vlan 2 and not shutdown or in another vlan and shut.

## Basic Code to get the interfaces into an array

```
  ##  BEGIN interfaces.sh ##
  #!/bin/bash
  clear
  ls *.cfg | while read config; do
  IFS=$'\r\n' interfaces=(`sed -n '/^interface/,/!/p' $config `)
  tLen=${#interfaces[@]}
  printf "\b Starting $config... \n"    
  for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ))
   do
    echo "${interfaces[$i]}" 
   done

  printf "\n\n"
  done
```

## One of the attempts I made

```
 #!/bin/bash
 clear
 ls *.cfg | while read config; do
 IFS=$'\r\n' interfaces=(`sed -n '/^interface/,/!/p' $config `)
 tLen=${#interfaces[@]}
 printf "\b Starting $config... \n"
 isInt=0
 isShut=0
 VLAN=0

 for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ))
 do
         if [[ $(echo "${interfaces[$i]}" | grep interface | grep net) ]]; then
                 int_name=${interfaces[$i]}
                 isInt=1
         fi

         if [[ $(echo "${interfaces[$i]}" | grep "access vlan" | grep -v "access vlan 2$") ]]; then
            VLAN="vlan1"
         fi

    if [[ $(echo "${interfaces[$i]}" | grep "access vlan 2$") ]]; then
                VLAN="vlan2"
    fi

         if [[ $(echo "${interfaces[$i]}" | grep -v " shutdown$") ]]; then
            isShut="notShutdown"
         fi

         if [[ $(echo "${interfaces[$i]}" | grep " shutdown$") ]]; then
                 isShut="shut"
    fi



    # This put here to test if the variables vlan and isShut is being set.
    # IF you uncomment this line you can see that the values are set then 
    # on the next pass it is changed of some of the values.  I dont know
    # how to fix this.
    #echo " $int_name vlan=$VLAN isShut=$isShut"

    # Below is the results of the value changing
    # interface Ethernet2/3 vlan=vlan1 isShut=notShutdown
    # interface Ethernet2/3 vlan=vlan2 isShut=notShutdown
    # interface Ethernet2/3 vlan=vlan2 isShut=notShutdown
    # interface Ethernet2/3 vlan=vlan2 isShut=shut
    # interface Ethernet2/3 vlan=vlan2 isShut=notShutdown
    # interface Ethernet2/3 vlan=vlan2 isShut=notShutdown
    # interface Ethernet2/3 is in vlan 2 and is not shutdown


         # End of interface section so reset counters
         if [[ "${interfaces[$i]}" == '!' ]]
           then
                 if [[ "$VLAN" == "vlan1" && "$isShut" == "notShutdown" ]]; then
                         echo "$int_name is NOT in vlan 2 and is not shutdown"
            fi

                 if [[ "$VLAN" == "vlan1" && "$isShut" == "shut" ]]; then
                         echo "$int_name is NOT in vlan 2 and is shutdown"
            fi

                 if [[ "$VLAN" == "vlan2" && "$isShut" == "notShutdown" ]]; then
                         echo "$int_name is in vlan 2 and is not shutdown"
            fi

                 if [[ "$VLAN" == "vlan2" && "$isShut" == "shut" ]]; then
                         echo "$int_name is in vlan 2 and is shutdown"
            fi

    isInt=0
    isShut=0
    vlan=0

         fi
 done

 printf "\n\n"
 done
```

## Begin Cisco Config #

```
  # Save this section as config.txt
Current configuration : 2271 bytes
 !
 ! Last configuration change at 18:30:45 CET Fri Jul 25 2014
 !
 version 15.0
 no service pad
 service timestamps debug datetime msec
 service timestamps log datetime msec
 no service password-encryption
 !
 hostname SW1
 !
 boot-start-marker
 boot-end-marker
 !
 !
 enable password cisco
 !
 no aaa new-model
 clock timezone CET 1
 !
 ip cef
 no ip domain-lookup
 !
 ipv6 unicast-routing
 ipv6 cef
 vtp domain CCIE
 vtp mode transparent
 !
 !
 !
 spanning-tree mode pvst
 spanning-tree extend system-id
 !
 vlan internal allocation policy ascending
 !
 vlan 11 
 !
 ! 
 !
 !
 !
 !
 !
 interface Loopback0
  ip address 6.6.7.7 255.255.255.255
 !
 interface Ethernet0/0
  duplex auto
  shutdown
 !
 interface Ethernet0/1
  no switchport
  ip address 6.6.17.7 255.255.255.0
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet0/2
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet0/3
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet1/0
  switchport access vlan 20
  switchport mode access
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet1/1
  switchport access vlan 5
  switchport mode access
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet1/2
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode access
  shutdown
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet1/3
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode access
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet2/0
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode access
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet2/1
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode access
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet2/2
  switchport access vlan 40
  switchport mode access
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet2/3
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode access
  shutdown
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet3/0
  switchport access vlan 10
  switchport mode access
  shutdown
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet3/1
  switchport access vlan 10
  switchport mode access
  shutdown
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet3/2
  switchport access vlan 10
  switchport mode access
  shutdown
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Ethernet3/3
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode access
  shutdown
  duplex auto
 !
 interface Vlan1
  no ip address
  shutdown
 !
 interface Vlan123
  ip address 6.6.123.7 255.255.255.0
  shutdown
 !
 !
 ip forward-protocol nd
 no ip http server
 !
 !
 !
 !
 !
 control-plane
 !
 !
 line con 0
  exec-timeout 0 0
  privilege level 15
  password cisco
  logging synchronous
 line aux 0
 line vty 0 4
  privilege level 15
  password cisco
  login
  transport input all
 !
 end
```

I hope I have explained this well enough.  This may be simple for you smarter guys out there but I am struggling with this.

Comment: This will be a horrible pain in BASH shell script. Is there the possibility of using more structured scripting language (e.g., Perl or Python)?

Comment: Yes perl would be an option, I am just not versed in perl.  My goal is to have a script that could be used in Linux and Solaris if possible.

Comment: I'm also not well versed in Perl. However, if Python is an option I can knock you together a portable script. Or, you ask for someone with more Perl under their belt. Either way, I'd recommend staying away from shell script because it difficult to make them robust.

Comment: Perhaps do you want to play with this: `sed -n '/^ interface /,/\!/p' config.txt | grep -e 'interface\|switchport access vlan\|shutdown\|!'`

Comment: Cyrus, that works to get the data from the file, but I am looking to generate a report/results file with only the interfaces that match or dont match the critera.  So in the report, I only want to identify the interfaces that ARE in VLAN 2 that are not shut and interfaces that ARE in any other VLAN that IS shut...

Comment: It was intended as a beginning for you.

Comment: Peter,  I would be interested in seeing how you could do it with a python script.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a Python 2.7 script and I've tried to make it robust. I use an IOS configuration file parser ([ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse)) library to avoid bugs in my own parsing attempt. I've given it a command line interface so to see the state of interfaces on vlan 2:

```
$ python interfaces.py --vlan 2 /path/to/ios.cfg
```

**Installation**

1. Install Python 2.7
2. Install cisoconfparse
3. Save the script below as some `.py` (e.g., `interfaces.py`)

**interfaces.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from itertools import ifilter
import sys

from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse


INTERFACE_REGEX = 'interface'
SWITCHPORT_REGEX = 'switchport access vlan'


def main(argv=None):
    args = parse_argv(argv=argv)
    parse = CiscoConfParse(args.conf_path)

    objs = parse.find_objects_w_child(INTERFACE_REGEX, SWITCHPORT_REGEX)
    records = (Record.from_ios_object(obj) for obj in objs)
    if args.vlan:
        records = ifilter(lambda r: r.vlan == args.vlan, records)

    for record in sorted(records, key=lambda r: r.name):
        print(record)


def parse_argv(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--vlan', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('conf_path')
    return parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])


class Record:
    def __init__(self, name, vlan, is_shutdown):
        self.name = name
        self.vlan = vlan
        self.is_shutdown = is_shutdown

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_shutdown:
            state = 'shutdown'
        else:
            state = 'running'
        return '{name} {vlan} {state}'.format(
            name=self.name,
            vlan=self.vlan,
            state=state
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_ios_object(cls, obj):
        tokens = obj.text.split()
        if len(tokens) != 2:
            raise ValueError('Expected 2 tokens, found ' + len(tokens))
        name = tokens[1]
        children = obj.re_search_children(SWITCHPORT_REGEX)
        if len(children) != 1:
            raise ValueError('Expected 1 matching child, found ' +
                             len(children))
        vlan = int(children[0].re_match('(\d+)$'))
        is_shutdown = bool(obj.re_search_children('shutdown'))
        return cls(name, vlan, is_shutdown)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: FYI... There are some non-trivial simplifications you could make to this script...  see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Storing each line of the input as a separate element in the array has complicated the processing. If you merge all of the interface definition into one array element it will simplify your lookups to simple string searches. An AWK mini-state-machine is one way to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.cfg | while read config; do
    interfaces=()
    IFS=$'\n'       # We'll delimit the records with this
    count=0
    printf "\b Starting $config... \n"    
    for i in $(awk '# ^interface = start of interface def; insert delimiter, set flag.
                    /^interface Ethernet/{inside_int=1}

                    # ! = end of interface def; unset flag.
                    (/!/ && inside_int){inside_int=0; print}

                    # if flag is set, print line
                    inside_int{printf "%s ", $0}

                    ' config.cfg ); do

        # append to interfaces array
        interfaces=(${interfaces[@]} $i)

        # Create three arrays with interface data

        # Interface name
        intname[$count]=$( echo "$i}" | sed -n "s/interface \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p" )

        # Interface VLAN
        vlan[$count]=$( echo "$i}" | sed -n 's/interface.*switchport access vlan \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' )

        # Interface up/down (0/1) status
        isdown[$count]=$( echo "$i}" | grep -c shutdown )

        ((count++))
    done

    # Loop and display values.
    for (( i=0; i<${#interfaces[@]}; i++ )); do
        echo -e "Int:${intname[$i]}\tvlan:${vlan[$i]}\tisdown:${isdown[$i]}"
    done
done
```

The `${intname[@]}`, `${vlan[@]}`, and `${isdown[@]}` arrays contain the individual values you were looking for. The `${interfaces[@]}` array contains the each interface definition as a separate element that can be string-searched for other data.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to parse hierarchical text files (like a Cisco IOS configuration) with `bash` scripts... use a canned configuration parsing library...

Improving on @PeterSutton's answer... [CiscoConfParse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse/) supports automated vlan parsing if you parse with `factory=True` (yes, I know this is still undocumented, but you can find all the possible parsing values in the source of [`ciscoconfparse/models_cisco.py`](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/blob/master/ciscoconfparse/models_cisco.py))...

The code for parsing out interface name, switchport status and access vlan number is this simple...

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
from prettytable import PrettyTable

parse = CiscoConfParse('config.text', factory=True)
table = PrettyTable(['Intf Name', 'Switchport?', 'Access Vlan (0 is no vlan)'])
for intf_obj in parse.find_objects('^interface'):
    table.add_row([intf_obj.name, intf_obj.is_switchport, intf_obj.access_vlan])

print table
```

When you run that, you get a text table...

```
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ python example.py 
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+
|  Intf Name  | Switchport? | Access Vlan (0 is no vlan) |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+
|  Loopback0  |    False    |             0              |
| Ethernet0/0 |    False    |             0              |
| Ethernet0/1 |    False    |             0              |
| Ethernet0/2 |    False    |             0              |
| Ethernet0/3 |    False    |             0              |
| Ethernet1/0 |     True    |             20             |
| Ethernet1/1 |     True    |             5              |
| Ethernet1/2 |     True    |             2              |
| Ethernet1/3 |     True    |             2              |
| Ethernet2/0 |     True    |             2              |
| Ethernet2/1 |     True    |             2              |
| Ethernet2/2 |     True    |             40             |
| Ethernet2/3 |     True    |             2              |
| Ethernet3/0 |     True    |             10             |
| Ethernet3/1 |     True    |             10             |
| Ethernet3/2 |     True    |             10             |
| Ethernet3/3 |     True    |             2              |
|    Vlan1    |    False    |             0              |
|   Vlan123   |    False    |             0              |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------------+
(py27_test)[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

You can use [`Inline::Python`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Python/Python.pod) to embed `ciscoconfparse` in a perl script... but you still wind up writing in python, so I'm not really sure what the point is for a task this simple.

---

**Disclaimer**: I am [CiscoConfParse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse/)'s author